# Providing internet access to users in an Enterprise (MPLS ) Network

Tags: internet, mpls

**Scenario**

I'm planning to setup a typical Head Office - Branch Office(s) Network Setup.

there will be 25 branch offices in India of two will be overseas (one in US and the other in UK). All these will be connected via MPLS.

**Additional details:**

No of Concurrent users in each office is going to be 25 tranlating to 650 users

The requirement is to provide "proxied" internet connectivity to the branch offices.

**How should I go about doing it?**

**Plan A:**

Buying an internet leased line in the Head Office and distribute it through an internal proxy server to all the branches

**Plan B**

Buying separate internet lines for all the branches and setup individual proxies to all the branch offices.

Answer (score 1):

We tried going with your Plan A for our office and it did not work out very well, The latency between branch offices and HO was too great and we ran into an incredible amount of problems. Also if the mpls would go down (rare but it happened a few times) then the entire branch office was down.

We have since went with a combination mpls for internal traffic to HO and individual internet lines for the internet.

Our offices are all over North America though but we still noticed issues with offices near the HO.